# Garbled text in Windows Explorer address bar

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, graphics

[image: Cropped screenshot of Explorer]

The text input field in the address bar is garbled, on top of the icon, and unusable. When I click on it with the regular arrow shaped cursor, then I cannot enter text. All kinds of graphics errors happen in the text entry field. What is shown in the screenshot is actually rather clean compared to what it can look like. When the window has no focus, then the text input field is covered by a black box.

*How can I fix this?*

It has been like that since perhaps three days, but I have no clue what may have caused it. I don't recall installing any software package or large update.

It's a ThinkPad X1 Tablet 3 with Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Have you tried repairing windows? `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

Comment: @SaaranshGarg Can't I just let it repair Exlorer, or reinstall Explorer? I don't like these commands that affect the entire system.

Comment: you're right — it does affect your entire system. But then, only thing it does is to repair corrupted system files, which is usually considered *good* since it helps improve performance. Unless you've modified system files yourselves, it is unlikely that `DISM` commands will you cause any kind of trouble or inconvenience. As for whether you can reinstall just explorer, it is impossible, since the explorer is far too well integrated with windows that it forms an essential part of the OS itself. Repair *just explorer*, AFAIK, no such command exists....

Comment: @SaaranshGarg Thank you, I'll have a look before running that command, to better understand what it does. I see that Adobe Acrobat added itself to Explorer, and maybe it's related to that, kind of a plague. It also does auto update in the background.